# Steam game won't launch, says 'running' for short while then stops

Tags: steam, technical-issues, geometry-dash

When i try to launch Geometry Dash, the following things happen:

1. 'Running' appears next to the game in my library.
2. A 'Preparing to Launch' window appears for a short while.
3. My profile picture turns green.

It stays like this for a while, maybe about 4 seconds, then the 'Running' message disappears and my profile picture returns to blue. There is never any error message or window.

I have tried everything that every forum says to do including:

- reinstalling the game
- verifying game files
- running from program files
- resinstalling visual c++
- reinstalling steam completly.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Specs:

- OS Name: Microsoft Windows 10 Home
- Version: 10.0.14393 Build 14393
- Processor:   Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7200U CPU @ 2.50GHz, 2701 Mhz, 2 Core(s), 4
- Logical Processor(s)
- RAM:     8Gb
- Graphics:    Intel(R) HD Graphics 620

#### Update: I used event viewer and located the prolbem to be in libcocos2d.dll

Faulting application name: GeometryDash.exe
Faulting module name: libcocos2d.dll, version: 0.0.0.0
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x000e8045
Faulting process id: 0x2268
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Geometry Dash\GeometryDash.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Geometry Dash\libcocos2d.dll

#### Update #2: Compatibility mode

I tried running it in every compatibility mode. It would never run if i tried the .exe in steam apps, but if i tried running it through the steam client, windows 95 and windows 98/me worked. however the audio quality in that the lower range of frequency were reduced to broken static.

#### Update #3: Solved

I have solved the problem and posted the solution as an answer

Comment: Did you try running compatibility mode for Windows 7 or Windows XP? If that works let me know and I'll craft an answer.

Comment: When running from program files, use a command shell to see if any error messages are being displayed

Comment: This happened to me a while back, contacted their support, no answer.

Comment: @npst I used event viewer and found it is a prolbem with libcocos2d.dll. I have updated the question

Comment: @Kaizerwolf Thanks for your help. I tried running it in every compatibility mode. I have updated the question.

Comment: Have you tried restarting Steam?  They recently introduced a problem where Steam doesn't work correctly on some machines when it boots up, and exactly this problem will occur with every game.  Restarting Steam seems to fix the issue.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft If you read the question, I state that I have tried completely reinstalling steam to no avail.

Comment: Have you updated everything on your computer? Drivers etc latest?

Comment: @Codingale yes, I have updated all drivers, software and my windows version

Comment: Well, on the interwebs they recommend updating both graphic card drivers and directX to a recent version to fix exactly your problem. On a side note, do you have a 32 or 64 bit OS?

Comment: @npst I have a 64 bit os, and I tried updating drivers through device manager and all graphics and display drivers should be up to date. Is there an automated way to update drivers?

Comment: Has it worked before, if so try an older version? Contacting the support team might be able to get you some more professional help.. not sure. About all I can do.

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer; it doesn't belong as part of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solved!

#### After many attempts, this prolbem has finally been resolved. This is how I did it.

In the end, all i needed to do was to completely uninstall Geometry Dash (or, I presume, what every game this problem is occuring with). First I uninstalled the game through the steam client. Then, I installed [void tools](https://www.voidtools.com/) everything. this is basically a very good and fast index searcher. By searching for 'geometry dash' I was able to delete all the files that were left on my pc after the game was supposedly uninstalled by steam. These files caused the problem. After this, I used the change/uninstall a program menu to uninstall steam, then reinstalled steam and downloaded the game and it worked.

Comment: Sometimes external libraries use an installer that doesn't really verify the files, so if the external libraries are corrupted, then the standard Uninstall/Install from Steam won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can manually start the game's executable outside of Steam and then manually close it.  This will reset its status with Steam.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE: THIS PROBABLY DOESN'T APPLY TO OP, BUT MAY HELP ANYBODY ELSE**

This has happened to me, and I have found a solution.

When your computer starts up, there is a Steam pop-up which says "Verifying installation" (or like that in the future or the past).

If you close that window, then Steam games will **not** start. Instead, you have to wait it out.

**TL;DR** Restart your computer and do not close out Steam.